# "The 'og:type' property is required, but not present." error, despite correct HTML

Tags: facebook-opengraph

This URL (http://www.di.fm/tracks/878723/ebm) gives an error on the OpenGraph debugger:

```
The 'og:type' property is required, but not present.
```

despite that the proper meta tag is set:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="company">
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no og:type "company", see the specification: http://ogp.me/#types

Also make sure to use http/https in your og:image definition. If you try to re-scrape your URL in the debugger, i only get the following error:

> Object at URL 'http://www.di.fm/tracks/878723/ebm' of type 'website'
>   is invalid because the given value
>   '//static.audioaddict.com/4/2/f/d/b/5/42fdb594090bfe550f483e0ee6971a9a.jpg'
>   for property 'og:image:url' could not be parsed as type 'url'.

...and add a slash at the end of each og tag, see here: http://ogp.me/

Comment: Thanks, Im aware of the image problem :)

Comment: you need to fix any error that appears, it is possible that the debugger does not re-scrape your page because of that error. and make sure everything is 1:1 as it is in the specification (see the last link i posted)

Comment: You mean, if the others bugs arent fixed, the og:type bug won't appear as fixed on the debugger?

Comment: could be a reason, yes. an error could prevent facebook from storing the new data.